# Spring change bean scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have the below bean which get a value from a database

```
@Bean
fun getCronValue(): String {
   val cron = settingRepository.findByKey("batch_cron_expression")
   return cron?.value ?: applicationProperties.batch.cronExpression
}
```

then i used this bean into the `@Scheduled`

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValue}")
```

i want when the value is changed from the database the bean read the new value automatically without needed to restarting the application

Comment: since the default spring bean scope is singleton and created at startup of application , for your requirement you might need to set bean scope to request . i hope it works

Comment: @Noshaf Couldn't you use prototype as bean scope?

Comment: @Twistleton yes correct .

Comment: If you're trying to change the schedule at runtime, you'll need to use a trigger.  Using the Scheduled annotation, it will be set to that value when the app starts, but it won't change its schedule if the value that bean produces changes.  By defining a trigger, you can modify its schedule dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Spring [RepositoryEventHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#events).

Sample code

application.properties:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

AppConfig:

```
    @Bean
    public LatestCustomerId customerIdLatest() {
        LatestCustomerId id = new LatestCustomerId();
        id.setId(-1);
        return id;
    }
```

CustomerEventHandler:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(CustomerDo.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerEventHandler {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @HandleAfterSave
    public void handleAuthorAfterSave(CustomerDo customerDo) {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
        registry.removeBeanDefinition("customerIdLatest");

        GenericBeanDefinition myBeanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        myBeanDefinition.setBeanClass(LatestCustomerId.class);
        myBeanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);

        MutablePropertyValues mpv = new MutablePropertyValues();
        mpv.add("id", Integer.valueOf(customerDo.getId()));
        myBeanDefinition.setPropertyValues(mpv);

        registry.registerBeanDefinition("customerIdLatest", myBeanDefinition);
    }
}
```

CustomerController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/customer")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;
    private final CustomerEventHandler customerEventHandler;

    @Autowired
    private LatestCustomerId latestCustomerId;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> createCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {

        CustomerDo customerDo = customerRepository.save(customerMapper.toCustomerDo(customerDto));
        customerDto = customerMapper.toCustomerDto(customerDo);

        customerEventHandler.handleAuthorAfterSave(customerDo);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customerDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```